# sql server http request not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I having facing an issue in sql server 2008 regarding http request using t-SQL. the url which i have used is working fine in url browser but when i include this url in code it gives "null". Please help me to solve the issue .

```
 Declare @Object as Int;
 Declare @ResponseText as NVARCHAR(MAX);


 Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelInformationRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3ChotelId%3E122212%3C%2FhotelId%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Coptions%3E0%3C%2Foptions%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelInformationRequest%3E'

 EXEC sp_OAMethod @object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

  Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

  Select @ResponseText

  Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: It would probably be a cleaner overall experience to use a CLR procedure and use the .NET http classes/methods. I seem to remember that the COM interop procedures are a pain to clean up properly in the even of errors.